# Добавление ведущих нулей к счетчику C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Написал счетчик по нажатию кнопки, сделал ведущие нули. Счетчик работает но целая часть не суммируется с дробной.

Например: 14.4 + 14.4 + 14.4 = 43.2 дробная часть отсекается и должна оставаться целая 43. Но у меня на выходе 42.

Без добавления ведущих нулей все выводится как надо.

Подскажите что делаю не так? Как правильно добавить ведущие нули?

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            double tick; //счетчик

            if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tick))
            {
            string fmt = "00000"; // ведущие нули
            tick = tick + 14.40;
            var p = Math.Truncate(tick); // отделение целой части
            //var t = Math.Round(tick % 1, 2); // дробная часть
            textBox1.Text = p.ToString(fmt);// ведущие нули

            }

            else

            textBox1.Text = @"0";
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть же документация по форматированию числа [`Double.ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netframework-4.8). Зачем вообще что-либо отделять?

Так же для дополнения строки символом до нужной длины есть метод [`String.PadLeft()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.8).

```cs
private double fix = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out double tick))
    {
        tick += 14.4 + fix;
        fix = tick - Math.Truncate(tick);
        textBox1.Text = tick.ToString("F0").PadLeft(7, '0');
    }
    else
        textBox1.Text = 0d.ToString("F0").PadLeft(7, '0');
}
```

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужно считать дробную часть но не нужно выводить ее в textBox.

Comment: @star1k поправил ответ.

Comment: Все работает как надо! Спасибо огромное что помогли разобраться! Для более точного результата подправил fix = tick - Math.Truncate(tick); на  fix = tick - Math.Round(tick);

Comment: @star1k `Math.Round` не сработает. Если внимательно изучите, как считает, сможете убедиться в этом. Если вы хотите использовать `Math.Round`, то вам при выводе строки так же надо его использовать `textBox1.Text = Math.Round(tick).ToString("F0").PadLeft(7, '0');`